# How to get segment and cluster using number of variables in R

Tags: python, r, dataframe, dplyr, data-science

I have a data frame which consists of the following data:

```
cus_id   sex    city    state      product_type   var1     var2     type     score
CA-1     Male   ABC     New York   type-1         10       10       P-1      750
CA-2     Female ABC     Alaska     type-2         10       9.5      P-2      850
CA-3     Male   Denver  dfdfd      type-3         10       11.1     P-3      560
CA-4     Female esx     Nsdfe      type-4         15       15       P-3      734
CA-5     Male   dfr     dfdedc     type-5         13       12.9     P-3      798
CA-6     Male   xds     Nsdfe      type-6         14.5     10.8     P-2      700
CA-7     Female edf     New York   type-5         14.2     14       P-2      550
CA-8     Female xde     New York   type-5         04       04       P-1      650
CA-9     Male   wer     New York   type-1         10       11       P-1      730
```

Using the above-mentioned data frame, I want to create a segment considering the variables `sex`, `City`, `State` and `score` for the below-mentioned independent parameters.

- product_type : is the static from type-1 to type-7
- type: is the static from P-1 to P-3

The score is range from 100 to 1000,that we can break as per the segment identified for `product_type` and `type`

I want to Identify the cluster where the difference of `var2` value from `var1` value is minimum in terms of percentage. For Example, for cus_id `CA-1` the match is 100% so we will have the segment for 100% with the matching sex, city, state and score variables.

I don't know how to make cluster using K means, Need approach and suggestion by SO.